# How do you turn off the Bedtime app alarm if you wake up before it?

Tags: iphone, ios

I've updated my phone to IOS10, one of the features I quite like is the bedtime app (and no longer needing a 3rd party app). Whilst the features are pretty easy to figure out I can't seem to figure out... how to turn off the Bedtime app alarm if you wake up before it?

E.g I woke up before the app, left the room, came back and the alarm was going off. Ideally I wanted to stop it before it started.

Answer (score 3):

To reiterate you will do the following.

1. Swipe up from the bottom of the screen. This will bring up your control center.
2. Tap timer.
3. Tap the bed time tab.
4. Switch off the whole thing by sliding the switch somewhere near the top to off.

Note, I'm visually impaired  so I'm depending on what my screen reader says the switches are to slide. If I'm wrong adjust where the switches are on your interface.

Comment: I suspect this will also stop the Clock app from writing your sleep data to the Health app.

Comment: It will, but you can always add this manually or use a different sleep data tracker for ios.

Comment: This doesn’t work for me. I was messing around with the app and put the time I wake up and the time I’d like to go to sleep. Not the health app has an alarm go off. I go to school and the alarm goes off during class. How do I permanently turn it off? You put a way to temararly turn it off. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After setting it up, there is no way to turn it off; you can just edit the time you want to wake up and the hours you want to sleep. You can, however, turn off the wake alarm.

Comment: How do you turn off the wake alarm?