# I'm using Bedtime incorrectly—but in what way?

Tags: alarm

I'm new to iOS and trying to understand how to use [Bedtime](https://help.apple.com/iphone/12/#/iph2909d3a74). Its documentation is sparse to nonexistent, and learning by trial and error is naturally impeded by the 24-hour cycle, so I've come here in the hope that others have already elucidated a more complete understanding of its behavior and intended use.

This just happened:

- **20:30** Set bedtime to 22:30–06:30.
- **23:50** Set bedtime to 00:00–08:00.
- **00:00** Start sleeping.
- **06:45** Stop sleeping. Start carrying the phone in my pocket while listening to a podcast.
- **07:42** Wonder about [#252617](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/252617/6408). Dismiss the "Do Not Disturb During Bedtime" notification. Open and close the Bedtime screen.
- **08:00** The wake-up alarm rings. Tap the stop button.

Expected outcome:

- The sleep interval is recorded as either 00:00–06:45 or 00:00–08:00.

Actual outcome:

- The sleep interval is recorded as 07:42–08:00:

  [image][image]

I don't understand how it came to that conclusion.

1. What is the mechanism by which that happened?
2. What should I do differently next time to ensure that the recorded interval more accurately reflects when I actually slept?

Comment: Have you seen [this Bedtime guide](https://mashable.com/article/iphone-bedtime-mode-how-to-use/#XFj6C1GBQOqZ) or other [similar guides](https://www.cultofmac.com/561853/ios-12-bedtime-mode-iphone/)?

Comment: Sure, I have now. Anything in particular I should be seeing there?

Comment: Nothing specific but since you were having problem I thought to ensure you're doing things correctly or understanding how things work by following a more detailed guide.